# Create an ID column in mysql based on year, month and then my custom number

Tags: php, mysql

I just want **150700001**, **150600001** `(yymm00001)` formatted `ID` column in mysql, that is also a `primary key`. I have tried this code below

```
 select ifnull(lpad(max(pid)+1,9, '0'), 
 concat(concat(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%y'), 
 DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m')),lpad('1',5,'0'))) pid 
 from patient_admission;
```

**I want:**

```
╔═══════════╗
║ 150600001 ║
║ 150600002 ║
║ 150600003 ║
║ 150700001 ║
║ 150600002 ║
╚═══════════╝
```

And so on

But It's does not returning the next month.
Thnx.

Comment: Do you want this part of the insert routine and automatic? With little or no php interaction? Is a stored proc ok?

Comment: No its not procedure, it's just an automayic and also without php interaction

Comment: Did you learn nothing from Y2K?

Comment: Can it be in a stored proc was my partial question

Comment: when i run this code 

select ifnull(lpad(max(pid)+1,9, '0'), concat(concat(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%y'), DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m')),lpad('1',5,'0'))) pid from patient_admission
in mysql editor, it return

150600009,  where it should be 150700001

Answer (score 0):

Here Is My Table Structure:

```
1.  pid {char(9), Primary Key}
2.  pname
3.  age
4.  gender
5.  marital_status
6.  profession
7.  father_name
8.  mother_name
9.  present_addr
10. permanent_addr
11. phone
12. contact_person_name
13. contact_person_phone
14. contact_person_relation
15. contact_person_addr
16. consultant_doctor
17. onduty_doctor
18. admission_fee
19. admission_date
20. bed_allotment
21. status
```

The Code above you have mention, it's already tested.

I am running this on CodeIgniter:

Model Part:

```
public function get_patient_id(){
$sql = "select ifnull(lpad(max(pid)+1,9, '0'), concat(concat(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%y'), DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m')),lpad('1',5,'0'))) pid from patient_admission";

$qry = $this->db->query($sql);
$ra = $qry->result_array();
return $ra[0];
}
```

Controller Part:

```
public function entry(){
$data['patient_id'] = $this->Patient_admission_model->get_patient_id();
$this->load->view( 'patient/admission/entry', $data );
```

}

Comment: Can you Just Suggest me that how can i get those kinds of value. Any suggestion will be helpful. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have successfully Done, jaust have to add where clues with a subquery:

```
select ifnull(lpad(max(pid)+1,9, '0'), concat(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%y%m'),lpad('1',5,'0'))) pid from patient_admission where id_generator = (select DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%y%m') id_generator)
```

> I just have created **id_generator** another column in patient_admission table
>   And gmdate( 'ym', time()+3600*6); this code to during insertion

that's All. By the way, thanks to All of you speatialy @Drew Pierce